# IOS app designed in React native stopped receving onesignal notificaiton

Tags: node.js, react-native, onesignal

I have made apps using react native and backend is node express js, both apps are live. I used onesignal for the notifications and notifications were coming perfectly on both the apps. But now suddenly ios app has stopped receiving the notifications but on android it is working perfectly. Although in onesingal dashboard notification is shown as delivered but still notification is coming in only ios app. I have searched in the documentation still didn't got anything

"react-native-onesignal": "^4.0.6", npm library version

Please help me with this. Any lead would be very helpful!!

Comment: You're saying onesignal was work on iOS until it wasn't. Did you make any change on your code?

Comment: no I haven't made any changes

Answer (score 0):

Check your OneSignal dashboard for error messages or warnings. Could be a problem with your APNs certs.